# How to display value of the array as needed?

Tags: php, arrays

My code like this :

```
<?php 
    $data1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    $data2 = array(
                array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'chelsea.jpg'),
                array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'mu.jpg'),
            );
    foreach ($data1 as $key1 => $value1) {
        foreach ($data2 as $key2 => $value2) {
            if($value1 == $value2['id'])
                echo $value2['name'].'<br>';
            else
                echo 'No data'.'<br>';
        }
    }
?>
```

If the code run, the result like this :

> chelsea.jpg
>
> No data
>
> No data
>
> mu.jpg
>
> No data
>
> No data
>
> No data
>
> No data
>
> No data
>
> No data

It's false

I want the result like this :

> chelsea.jpg
>
> mu.jpg
>
> No data
>
> No data
>
> No data

How can I do it?

Comment: store the values in an array and sort it .

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually want to do or how this result you want to create is actually meant to be achieved. I cannot any immediate logic leading to that result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the second array so that it's keyed by the id column.  This allows you to do an isset rather than any other sort of lookup...

```
<?php
$data1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$data2 = array(
        array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'chelsea.jpg'),
        array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'mu.jpg'),
);
$data2 = array_column($data2, null, 'id' );
foreach ($data1 as $key1 => $value1) {
    if(isset($data2[$value1]))
        echo $data2[$value1]['name'].'<br>';
            else
        echo 'No data'.'<br>';
}
?>
```

Update:  after thinking about how to minimise the code, using PHP7's null coalesce ?? operator...

```
 <?php
    $data1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    $data2 = array(
            array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'chelsea.jpg'),
            array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'mu.jpg'),
    );
    $data2 = array_column($data2, null, 'id' );
    foreach ($data1 as $value1) {
        echo $data2[$value1]['name']??'No data'.'.<br>';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) when you find an `id`:

```
$data1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$data2 = array(
            array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'chelsea.jpg'),
            array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'mu.jpg'),
        );
foreach ($data1 as $key1 => $value1) {
    foreach ($data2 as $key2 => $value2) {
        if($value1 == $value2['id']) {
            echo $value2['name'],"\n";
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    echo "No data\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
chelsea.jpg
mu.jpg
No data
No data
No data
```

Comment: Fine for a small set of values, but doesn't really scale.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **in_array** php function to do this

Use this:-

```
$data1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$data2 = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'chelsea.jpg'),
    array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'mu.jpg'),
);
foreach ($data2 as $key2 => $value2) {
    if(in_array($value2['id'],$data1))
        echo $value2['name'].'<br>';
    else
        echo 'No data'.'<br>';
}
```

It will give output as

[image]

**Modified:-**

```
$data1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$data2 = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'chelsea.jpg'),
    array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'mu.jpg'),
);
foreach ($data1 as $key1 => $value1) {
    $name='No data';
    foreach ($data2 as $key2 => $value2) {
        if($value1 == $value2['id'])
            $name= $value2['name'];
    }
    echo $name.'<br>';
}
```

It give output as

[image]

Comment: Clever but main source is $data1 against $data2 so count $data1 is important I think.

Comment: But both are present here so OP can do like this.

Comment: This doesn't give the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will be helpful.

```
<?php 
    $data1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    $data2 = array(
                array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'chelsea.jpg'),
                array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'mu.jpg'),
            );
    foreach ($data1 as $key1 => $value1) {
        foreach ($data2 as $key2 => $value2) {
            if($value1 == $value2['id'])
                echo $value2['name'] . "<br/>";
            else
                $new_array[] = 'No data';
        }
    }

echo implode("\n", $new_array);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php 
    $data1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    $data2 = array(
                array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'chelsea.jpg'),
                array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'mu.jpg'),
            );
    $isFound = false;
    foreach ($data1 as $key1 => $value1) {
        foreach ($data2 as $key2 => $value2) {
            if($value1 == $value2['id']){
                echo $value2['name'].'<br>';
                $isFound = true;
            }
        }
        if(!$isFound){
           echo "no data";
           $isFound = false; 
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: IMHO $isFound flag add too much complexity there without good reason. Else would be better choice.

Comment: you need to put `$isFound = false;` inside the outer loop  so you can reset the flag for each loop , without that the flag will always be true after first occurrence

Comment: still not the desired result, you need to put `$isFound = false;` right after the outer loop `foreach ($data1 as $key1 => $value1) {` see that demo [https://eval.in/830007](https://eval.in/830007)